# Is show the database ID's to the user unsafe?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm developing a football betting app and as it is right now my users can see the Id's of their bets and other registers, the thing is I'm looking up to some similar apps and none of them let their users see the Id, instead they  provide an authentication hex like this '7A1D.63DF.146F'. So, do I need to worry about that? And just for curiosity, are those authentications generated based on my Id number or it has nothing to do with it? I'd like to know how to generate them. Thank's in advance!

Comment: You have to obscure your code as much as you can . I will suggest you to hide as much as you can. One more thing if these Urls can make writing changes , Then it is alarming .

Comment: Yes bro,You have to hide your id or encrypt with some hashing methods like md5 function.

Comment: It's not inherently unsafe - sequential numeric keys are just easy to guess if you're hacking someone else's account; but if your security is so lax that it *matters* that the user can see a primary key from the database then you've got bigger problems than the fact that they *can* see it.

Comment: They can do nothing, as far as I know at least, with the URLs since It's a Cordova Application. I don't think It would be a problem if they see the Id's but since everybody else doesn't allow that It got me thinking. Also would be important to notice that they will use the Id's to search for bets in the system. So, what do you guys recommend? Do I use the standard Id or do I generate a md5? If I go with the md5 how can I format it to the pattern above so It can be more easily read?

Comment: It's not unsafe necessarily. Many webpages have URLs like `/page/142` where 142 is the primary key or other ID. It should be protected anyway - that is, check the user can see the ID before loading - never trust the value passed from the request as it can be easily spoofed. There's no need to MD5 or encrypt IDs as other users suggested!

Comment: What is the point in showing the MD5 ID to the user? Is your web app using the ID in it's Javascript or something - in which case, MD5ing it won't help you anyway. It really all depends on your use case...

Comment: As I said, the user must be able to search his bets, wich has an ID, in the system, so my doubt is wich one is the better call? Search with the ID itself or provide an identification number like this '7A1D.63DF.146F'? Most apps I know use that identification number. If that's the case how can I generate that format?

Comment: Just to clearify, I have this control panel and webservice written in php. The control panel connects directly to the database and the app uses ajax calls to communicate with the service. The user can see the id's on the the web app but I'm not concerned about this. My doubt is only if it makes easier to the users to search for their registers, since every time I make a bet I print a receipt that contains the id number or the Identification Pattern I decide to use.

Comment: Your web service needs to authenticate the user who's making the request - it shouldn't matter if "Bob" sees that his receipt is 123, the service should only respond to "Bob" when requesting receipts that are assigned to him - if he knocks up a quick script that calls your service with any arbitrary id, then your service should respond with something like "Access Denied" if the user isn't authenticated *and* the "owner" of that receipt.

Comment: Ok, I'll make shure that all that stuff is taken care of. Thank you guys.

Comment: Like others have said, securitywise it shouldn't be a concern. I do however remember reading a note from a guy about this, with a different perspective: If ID numbers are available then people might be able to see how large the database actually is. Which could then potentially be used by a competitor or similar in some situations. Obviously it depends on system design, it has to be open so that competitors can view your site to begin with.

Comment: Only the system manager can access the web app.